# how to copy directory & contents of directory with parent directory structure at root level in generated war file using gradle script

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

Hi I am newbie to gradle script, I am trying to copy **directory** to **root** directory of war file, but I ended up copying **only the contents** of the folder to **root** directory, but I want the whole **directory structure with parent directory** also to be copied.

**Folder structure to copy**

```
polymer-client
├── file1.txt
├── index.html
```

**Gradle script**

```
apply plugin: 'war'
war {
    archiveName = 'WebDeployment.war'
    from 'polymer-client'
}
```

**Generated folder structure**

```
WebDeployment
├── WEB-INF
├── META-INF
├── file1.txt
├── index.html
```

**Expected folder structure**

```
WebDeployment
├── WEB-INF
├── META-INF
├── polymer-client
    ├── file1.txt
    ├── index.html
```

Please let me know, how to get it done with gradle script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to do it with `into` as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'war'
war {
    archiveName = 'WebDeployment.war'
    into 'polymer-client', {
        from 'polymer-client'
    }
}
```

It should create the `polymer-client` subdirectory within war-archive and copy all the content of the `polymer-client` directory into it.